# Wysihtml5 editor - Limit number of characters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, iframe, wysihtml5

I have this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-11">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Description<span>*</span></label>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "editor", @maxlength = "500" })<br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
     </div>
</div>
```

and the js for the wysihtml5 editor (using **Razor engine**):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.editor').wysihtml5({
        stylesheets: "/Content/css/wysiwyg-color.css",
        charset: "utf-8"
    })
</script>
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is limit the number of characters *(500 char max)* in this field. As you can see, I've set the `maxlength` attribute in the `@Html.TextAreaFor`, but it didn't worked.

Can someone please show me how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use an id for your textarea, intead of a class.
[Wysihtml5](http://xing.github.io/wysihtml5/) uses this id to create an iframe.

The id it uses for the iframe is `"[your textarea id]-sandbox"`.
Since this element is dynamically created, I updated the code below *(This is an edited answer)*.

```
$(document).ready(function{
    var PreventSubmitFlag=false;

    $('#editor').sibling("#editor-sandbox").find("body").on("keyup", function(e){
        var content = $(this).html();
        if(content.length>500){
            alert ("500 characters is the limit!");
            PreventSubmitFlag=true;
        }else{
            PreventSubmitFlag=false;
        }
    });
});
```

Use `PreventSubmitFlag` to disable a submit button.
;)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working as well, the alert pop-up doesn't even show up. I've tried changing the `editor-sandbox` to `wysihtml5-sandbox` and `editor.wysihtml5-sandbox` but nothing happened. I can't seem to figure out why...